# Wick contraction corresponding to a connected diagram in $\phi^4$-theory to second order

Tags: feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

I am trying to understand the diagrams that comes from a two-point correlation function, $$\langle \Omega|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|\Omega\rangle$$, in $\phi^4$-theory. The zeroth order contribution, i.e. $\lambda^0$, is simply $D_F(x-y)$, and  in $\lambda^1$ we get an additional internal point such that $$-\underbrace{12}_{\text{possible connected contractions}}\frac{i\lambda}{4!}\int d^4z \phi(x)\phi(y)(\phi(z))^4\\ = -12\frac{i\lambda}{4!}\int d^4z D_F(x-z)D_F(z-z)D_F(y-z)$$
As for the contributions from the $\lambda^2$ term I can understand 2 of the 3 connected contractions of $\phi(x)\phi(y)(\phi(z))^4(\phi(w))^4$. The first one is $$-P\frac{\lambda^2}{4!4!}\int d^4z d^4w D_F(x-z)D_F(y-z)D_F(z-w)D_F(z-w)D_F(w-w),$$
and the second one is 
$$-P\frac{\lambda^2}{4!4!}\int d^4z d^4w D_F(x-z)D_F(y-w)D_F(z-w)D_F(z-z)D_F(w-w),$$ where $P$ is the possible configurations of the contraction. The third contraction yields the last diagram in the photo below[image], while the other diagrams correspond to the contractions above. **My question is really how the last diagram would look in terms of contractions when using Wick's theorem. What does the expression look like for that diagram?** There's clearly something i have misunderstood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the third $\lambda^2$ diagram is a little bit unusual in that there are three lines going between the two vertices, the rule continues to apply that there is a factor of $D_F$ for each line, meaning that the third $\lambda^2$ term is
$$-P\frac{\lambda^2}{4!4!}\int d^4z d^4w D_F(x-z)D_F(y-w)[D_F(z-w)]^3\ .$$
(I've continued using your notation of identifying the vertices as $z$ and $w$ in the expression, even though they are identified as $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the diagram.)

You've actually already correctly used multiple identical factors of $D_F$ when multiple lines connect two vertices; your expression for the first $\lambda^2$ term contains two factors of $D_F(z-w)$.

For calculating $P$, there are eight ways that the $\phi(x)$ can contract with one of the four $\phi(z)$'s or four $\phi(w)$'s, four ways that the $\phi(y)$ can contract with whichever of $\phi(z)$ or $\phi(w)$ that $\phi(x)$ didn't contract with, and $3!$ ways that the remaining three $\phi(z)$'s can contract with the remaining three $\phi(w)$'s, so
$$P=8\cdot 4\cdot 3!=192\ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually realized this a few moments before i read your answer and I was ready to make a comment with my explanation, but you beat me to it! Ah, I didn't notice that the labels for the internal points were $z_{1,2}$ in the photo.

Comment: You're missing a factor of two in your last expression ($4 \times 4 \times 3! = 96$). I think the reason is that for the first contraction of $\phi(x)$ with whether one of the four $\phi(z)$ or one of the four $\phi(w)$ you have eight possible contractions in total.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoRamos I think you're right. I fixed my answer. Thank you for pointing out my error.